# How to wrap line in PyDev's interactive console?

Tags: eclipse, console, pydev, word-wrap

Each time I want to view a long output line, I have to drag the horizontal scroll bar. Is it possible to set word wrapping in PyDev's interactive console (not editor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it's not currently possible to enable word wrapping in the PyDev interactive console.

You may report this as a feature request in https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev (but even better would be providing a pull request for that -- see: http://www.pydev.org/developers.html)

Comment: I just raised feature request Ticket 862 for that. Any scope how much effort would be involved for one of us to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible as of PyDev 6.2.  By default it is not enabled.  To see the icon that you have to click to enable visit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVGxx.jpg).  For the possibility that the link disappears, go to the console tab and you will want to look for an icon which has a yellow "left-turn" arrow and click that.